# grant trigger to schema not working

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I need to give an user TRIGGER permission for an whole schema in mysql to import mysql workbench backup.

I tried with:

```
grant trigger ON `schemaname`.* TO `user`@`localhost`
```

But while importing there comes the error that the user haven't the permissions.

```
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 53: TRIGGER command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'table'
```

I tried to give the user TRIGGER permission to the table - that works, but of course only for that table, for the others still came the error.

Is there any way to give an user trigger permission to an schema without giving him the permission for every table separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

```
In MySQL 5.0 CREATE TRIGGER requires the SUPER privilege.
```

So you need to give SUPER privileges to the User. While importing, there will be command like "Create Trigger..." which is throwing an error.

Check your MySQL version and definer value as well for trigger in the importing file.

**Edit:**
For version 5.1, follow [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html), that says:

```
CREATE TRIGGER requires the TRIGGER privilege for the table associated with the 
trigger. The statement might also require the SUPER privilege, depending on 
the DEFINER value, as described later in this section. If binary logging is 
enabled, CREATE TRIGGER might require the SUPER privilege, as described in 
Section 19.7, “Binary Logging of Stored Programs”. (Before MySQL 5.1.6, there is 
no TRIGGER privilege and this statement requires the SUPER privilege in all cases)

The DEFINER clause determines the security context to be used when checking access
privileges at trigger activation time.
```

So, you need to check Definer value for importing trigger. It might have something like : `DEFINER = root`. Try removing the definer then try importing. Hope it works...

Comment: But the create trigger works if I grant the privilege of an single table. Is there no other way to give an user the permission to create triggers for the whole database schema? I think to give SUPER privilege is overpowered for that? Next problem is, if I grant trigger permissions first to every single table, I get the error 'table doesn't exist'. Is the only way to export the schema only, import it. grant privileges and run the whole backup import?

Comment: I'm using mysql version 5.1.61.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL docs:

```
To relax the preceding conditions on function creation (that you must have the
SUPER privilege and that a function must be declared deterministic or to not
modify data), set the global log_bin_trust_function_creators system variable
to 1. By default, this variable has a value of 0, but you can change it like
this:

mysql> SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
You can also set this variable by using the
--log-bin-trust-function-creators=1 
option when starting the server.
```

Set the global variable and reopened the session I was able to insert the trigger